# Get keys of a deeply nested dictionary by the nesting level

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a multilevel dictionary, imagine something like:

```
raw_dict = {'a':{'b':{'c':[1,2,3]}},
            'd':{'e':{'f':{'g':[4,5,6]}}}}
```

Is it possible to access the keys of a specified nesting level?

That is, is there a way to do something like:

```py
level = 1
keys_level_1 = list([a way to call the dictionary at specified nesting level])
print(keys_level_1)
```

which will return

```
['b', 'e']
```

[this is similar](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-particular-nested-level-items-from-dictionary/), but not exactly what I want.

Comment: why isn't the answer in the link not what you are searching for? you only want the `keys` instead of `key:value` pairs ?

Comment: @Rabinzel in the link you get the keys only if their value is not a dictionary. I need all the keys (regardles the value!) at a specified level.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function

```
def get_keys(dct, level):
    
    def get_(d, current=0):
        # check if we're at the level we want, yield if so
        if current==level:
            yield d
        # if not, move down one more level
        else:
            for v in d.values():
                # only move down if the value is a dict
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    yield from get_(v, current+1)
                    
    return [x for s_l in get_(dct) for x in s_l]

raw_dict = {'a':{'b':{'c':[1,2,3]}},
            'd':{'e':{'f':{'g':[4,5,6]}}}}

get_keys(raw_dict, 0)
['a', 'd']
get_keys(raw_dict, 1)
['b', 'e']
get_keys(raw_dict, 2)
['c', 'f']
get_keys(raw_dict, 3)
['g']
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility using a recursive function:

```
raw_dict = {'a':{'b':{'c':[1,2,3]}},
            'd':{'e':{'f':{'g':[4,5,6]}}}}

def get_level(d, level):
    from itertools import chain
    
    if level == 0:
        return list(d)
    else:
        return list(chain.from_iterable(get_level(d[item], level=level-1)
                          for item in d if isinstance(d[item], dict)))

get_level(raw_dict, level=1)
```

output: `['b', 'e']`

other examples:

```
get_level(raw_dict, level=0)
['a', 'd']

get_level(raw_dict, level=1)
['b', 'e']

get_level(raw_dict, level=2)
['c', 'f']

get_level(raw_dict, level=3)
['g']

get_level(raw_dict, level=4)
[]
```